# Using jQuery sortable or droppable to put items into categories?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to place products in to cateogories, like

```
<ul id="Category1"></ul>
<ul id="Category2"></ul>

<ul id="Available">
 <li id="prod1">Product1</li>
 <li id="prod2">Product2</li>
</ul>
```

I want to drop the available products in to a category and when its dropped to post the update back via ajax. It doesn't really matter what is posted back, whether it's the updated category or all the categories.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr:even").css("background", "#f7f7f7");
    $("ul.drop").sortable({
        connectWith: 'ul',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        stop: function(ev, ui) {
             ?????
        }
    });
});
```

Can i make this work or should I be using drag and drop?

Answer (score 1):

Hi
This is the best example but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/xpmAt/

```
$("ul.basket").sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul.basket',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // Get all Category1 and Category2 selected products and
        // populate matching fields
        jQuery('#selected1').val(jQuery('#Category1 li').map(function() {return this.id;}).get().join(','));
        jQuery('#selected2').val(jQuery('#Category2 li').map(function() {return this.id;}).get().join(','));
    }
});
```